# Filed to run Contiki applications in QEMU

Tags: operating-system, qemu, contiki

I was trying to play with several tiny operating systems in an emulator but got stuck with Contiki in QEMU. Ideally the compiled executable should be run as a kernel in QEMU. For all OS's I was playing with I used this simple command to run executables in QEMU:

> qemu-system-*platform* -nographic -kernel *compiled_executable*

In the case of Contiki, QEMU freezes regardless of any target platform the executables are compiled for, even for target platform "native", which according to the documentation, is built with "x86 gcc".

I also tried ARM-based platforms with the same freezing issues. If I specify a correct CPU model (e.g. cortex-m3 for cc2538dk), I received a segmentation fault instead.

I am wondering if I was missing any steps to cause the QEMU to freeze. Does it mean that the compiled executable cannot be treated as kernels (yet), unless I provide some QEMU-specific codes to initialize QEMU as a "board" for Contiki?

Answer (score 1):

The native platform is used to build a "natively" (i.e. on Linux or other OS) executable image of Contiki - an userland app, rather than an OS kernel.

Comment: The original question description might be a bit misleading... I did try ARM-based target platform as well, with the same freezing issues. If I specify the correct CPU model (e.g. cortex-m3 for cc2538dk), I got a segmentation fault error. Does this mean even executable image for embedded boards cannot be treated as OS Kernels as well? Thanks!